# Not getting expected output in the Multithreading question

Tags: c#, multithreading

> Task description:
>
> Write a program that reads an positive integer value **n** (**n** > 3), then
> creates **n** threads (each thread has `id`; `id` starts from 1) and works
> until it receives a stop signal. All of **n** threads are waiting for a
> signal. Every second main thread sends a signal for a random thread,
> then that thread should print its `id` and return to a waiting state.
>
> Requirements:
>
> All additional threads should be finished correctly. At the thread
> function exit, a message about exit should be printed. While the
> thread is waiting for the condition variable, spurious wakeup should
> be checked. Only `std::cout` allowed for text output. Stop signal is
> `SIGINT (ctrl+c)`.

I have written the following code for the above question but in output, all the threads are not exiting. I am not able to figure out the problem as I am new to this topic. Any kind of help will be really appreciated.

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var numberofthreads = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        ProcessingClass myobject = new ProcessingClass();
        myobject.createThreads(numberofthreads);
    }
}

public class ProcessingClass
{
    public Mutex mymutex = new Mutex();

    private bool thread_flag = false;

    public void createThreads(int numberofthreads)
    {
        var threads = new List<Thread>(numberofthreads);
        for (int i = 0; i < numberofthreads; i++)
        {
            Thread th = new Thread(() =>
            {
                threadsworking();
            });

            th.Name = "Thread" + i;
            th.Start(); // <-- .Start() makes the thread start running   
            threads.Add(th);
        }

        Console.CancelKeyPress += (object sender, ConsoleCancelEventArgs e) =>
        {
            var isCtrlC = e.SpecialKey == ConsoleSpecialKey.ControlC;
            if (isCtrlC)
            {
                thread_flag = true;
                int num = 1;
                foreach (var thread in threads)
                {
                    thread.Join();
                    Console.WriteLine($"Thread {num} exits");
                    num++;
                }

            }
            e.Cancel = true;
        };

    }

    public void threadsworking()
    {
        while (thread_flag == false)
        {
            mymutex.WaitOne();   // Wait until it is safe to enter.  
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", Thread.CurrentThread.Name);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);    // Wait until it is safe to enter. 
            mymutex.ReleaseMutex();    // Release the Mutex.  
        }
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUXxV.png)

Comment: This statement doesn't make sense: _" sometimes only few threads are existing and sometimes all threads are existing"_. The output you show does not demonstrate that problem. You start 15 threads, and all 15 threads appear to exist. They also **exit** (in case you are confused about the two words, which are completely different). Please fix your question so it's clear what you're asking. While you're at it, make sure you edit the code to remove all unnecessary whitespace/blank lines, fix indentation, etc. so the code is actually reasonable to read. See [mcve] and [ask].

Comment: Wrong language! You say _"Only `std::cout` allowed for text output. Stop signal is `SIGINT (ctrl+c)`"_. That C++

Comment: @Flydog57: to be clear, `std::cout` is a C++ thing, but SIGINT/Ctrl+C is an OS-level thing and is just as applicable in C# as in C++.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Thanks for pointing out the mistakes. Corrections have been implemented.

Comment: @snehashukla Are you still encountering unexpected behavior, if so could you update the post to include that information so we can better assist you.

Comment: @DekuDesu Thankyou so much for your answer. It worked. I would like to ask you one small thing, as per the description of the task , is the solution correct ?

Comment: Honestly no, the main difference I see is that the requirements state that the `main` thread should call a random thread and that thread should respond with it's number. Meanwhile your code has every thread simply states it's id with no interaction from the main thread other than waiting for the mutex. But now your code works so it should be easy to shift that to meeting the requirements.

Comment: @DekuDesu Thankyou so so very much for your feedback. I will definitely try that and update you. I can't tell you how much your help means to me.

Comment: Not a problem, that's quite literally what we are here for! =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider preventing `mutex` from blocking threads from exiting.

When you use `mutex.WaitOne()` it blocks execution until the `Mutex` is owned by that thread. This can be really helpful for ensuring a thread has exclusive control over a shared resource. However, where this becomes a problem is when you want to arbitrarily end those threads such as when you invoke the event on the `Console.CancelKeyPress`.

You can see the effects of this by logging before and after the `thread.Join()` call you do in the event.

```cs
thread_flag = true;
int num = 1;
foreach (var thread in threads)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Joining {thread.Name}");
    
    thread.Join();
    
    Console.WriteLine($"Joined {thread.Name}");
    
    Console.WriteLine($"Thread {num} exits");

    num++;
}
```

When we do that logging it will show us that when you call `Join()` on Thread # 1 you see `Joining 1`. Then there is a *really* long pause, other threads still are doing work, and then *finally* all the threads join back to back.

The reason for this is - while `Join()` is waiting for Thread 1 to finish, Thread 1 is still waiting for the mutex.

Even though you set the `thread_flag` flag to `true`, Thread 1 can't exit because it hasn't taken ownership of the mutex to perform it's work and eventually exit the `while()` loop.

We can solve this issue fairly simply.

**Consider using a timeout when waiting for the mutex**
When you call `.WaitOne(n)` on the `mutex` you can wait for `n` given milliseconds and *give up* taking ownership of the mutex.

This will allow more frequent evaluations of the `while` loop, and subsequently more times that the `threadsworking` method checks to see if it should exit(using the `thread_flag` flag).

Heres a short example how implementing that change might look

```cs
public void threadsworking()
{
    while (thread_flag == false)
    {
        // wait to enter the mutex, give timeout to prevent blocking 
        // until mutex opens and use the bool returned to determine
        // if we should release the mutex or not
        if (mymutex.WaitOne(1))
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", Thread.CurrentThread.Name);
                Thread.Sleep(1000);    // Wait until it is safe to enter. 
            }
            finally
            {
                // make sure even if we encounter an error the mutex is released
                mymutex.ReleaseMutex();    // Release the Mutex.
            }
        }

        // allow other threads to continue their work instead of blocking with a while loop, this is optional depending on the workload
        Thread.Yield();
    }
}
```